# Why does openssl -trusted_first option behave differently from X509_V_FLAG_TRUSTED_FIRST environment variable?

Tags: openssl, letsencrypt

I've a perl script that runs openssl to locally check certificates' validity.  I don't want to just set an env var and walk away. This feels more like something is funny with my openssl installation or configuration

## What is the system, versions…

I'm locally validating certificates from Letsencrypt. This is a 20.04/Focal system. Openssl is `OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020` and so I would expect it to happy validate certs, even with LE "cross-signing" them using the new ISRG root cert.

However, once the old X3 cert expired, these errors began…

```
openssl verify -verbose -purpose sslserver -CAfile /path/redacted/chain.pem /path/redacted/cert.pem
C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1. 
error 2 at 2 depth lookup: unable to get issuer certificate. 
error /path/redacted/cert.pem: verification failed
```

This felt strange. Some digging led me to wonder about the `-trusted_first` option to `openssl verify`. This is exactly what openssl *would* complain if trusted-first option is *not* enabled. Trying to explicitly enable that option however, has no affect:

```
openssl verify -trusted_first -verbose -purpose sslserver -CAfile /path/redacted/chain.pem /path/redacted/cert.pem
C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
error 2 at 2 depth lookup: unable to get issuer certificate
error /path/redacted/cert.pem: verification failed
```

Ok, fine. That option *should* be on [by default since openssl 1.1.1](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set_hostflags.html) (that's this system, see above). So my explicitly including it should make no difference.

But eventually I tried specifying it as an env var. Wait, wat? Why does specifying this environment variable fix openssl's behavior to trust the first root cert it finds in the chain:

```
set X509_V_FLAG_TRUSTED_FIRST openssl verify -trusted_first -verbose -purpose sslserver -CAfile /path/redacted/chain.pem /path/redacted/cert.pem
```

…runs with exit value of zero.

## zooming out

I don't understand why openssl doesn't Just Work(tm). This is a fully updated 20.04. The newer ISRG root cert is installed in `/etc/ssl/certs/ISRG_Root_X1.pem` and `update-ca-certificates` is happy:

```
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that is not how you set an environment variable before running a command.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html

For example, I think you'd want something like

```
X509_V_FLAG_TRUSTED_FIRST=1 openssl verify -trusted_first -verbose -purpose sslserver -CAfile /path/redacted/chain.pem /path/redacted/cert.pem
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues here.

First, as RyanTM mentions, you're not setting the environment variable correctly. The exit 0 is coming from `set`, not the openssl command.

Second, `X509_V_FLAG_TRUSTED_FIRST` is not an environmental variable. Using it as an environmental variable won't do anything in OpenSSL.

[Check out the man page for more details.](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set_flags.html) Note this is from "man3" which is for C library functions.